# text Align :'right' doesn't work for placeholder when multiline is true

Tags: react-native

In my code i have 2 textInputs, one has one line and the other has multiple lines, the input is arabic so i have to enable textAlign: 'right', 
my problem is when i set multilines to true, the placeholder text remains on the left side of the text input, 
any idea how to solve this?
my code is the following:

View:

```
<View  style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    <TextInput
        style={forms.textInput}
        value={this.state.telephone}
        placeholder={'رقم هاتفك'}
        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'} 
        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({telephone: val}) } />
    <Icon name="android-phone-portrait" size={27} color="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 24 }}/>
</View>
<View  style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    <TextInput
        style={[forms.textInput,{height: 120}]}
        multiline={true}
        value={this.state.desc}
        numberOfLines={4}
        placeholder={'اقتراحك'}
        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'} 
        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({desc: val}) }/>
    <Icon name="ios-help-outline" size={27} color="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 24 }}/>
</View>
```

Style:

```
 textInput: {
    height: 40, 
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
    borderWidth: 2,
    margin: 15,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
    paddingRight: 40,
    textAlign :'right'
  },
```

______________________*******________________________

[image]

______________________*******________________________

Comment: I have the same issue, although with 'centre'. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually made a pull request for this which has been accepted and will be in the `0.29.0` release of react-native.

My fix was to add this line

`_placeholderView.textAlignment = _textView.textAlignment;`

to `react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextView.m`

Inside the `updatePlaceholder` function (right before `[self insertSubview:_placeholderView belowSubview:_textView];`)

[GitHub Commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/97c483ec29190d283cea30747dac979fd5143a33)